# Quando fazer testes de unidade em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, testes, testes-de-unidade, jasmine

Até onde é vantajoso fazer testes de unidade na camada de apresentação, e,
quais seriam os cenários em que o testes de unidade em Javascript é vantajoso?

Só é vantajoso se tiver cálculos no Javascript?

**Obs**.: Vou utilizar o Jasmine para os testes.

Comment: Fazer testes é sempre uma boa prática, tendo em vista que você não o quanto um determinado sistema vai evoluir

Answer (score 2):

Partindo de Engenharia de Software (mas resumindo). Testes de unidades são derivados de casos de testes, que por sua vez são baseados em casos de uso. Você precisaria ter uma documentação do seu sistema com:

- **Lista de Requisitos** ou diretrizes básicas do seu sistema. *Nada de incluir animações, interfaces*. Devem somente tratar descrição de funcionalidades, sendo o mais simples possível e não genéricos. Ex: O sistema deverá permitir que o usuário altere suas credenciais.
- Para cada requisito, montasse um ou mais **Casos de Usos**, citando detalhadamente como usuário irá utilizar o sistema para realizar o Requisito.

Assim para cada **caso de uso**, cria-se mais de um **caso de teste**, com entradas, saídas esperadas, e saídas obtidas. Veja que não é possível criar um caso de teste para interface, pois a interface não é um Requisito do Sistema.

Isso se deve porque a **interface** é uma camada superficial do sistema ela depende totalmente de algo que precisa ser testado, logo deixa de ser um teste **unitário** verdadeiro. Além disso a sua interface poderia transmitir entradas erradas para o próximos níveis do sistema, dificultando a identificação das saídas.

Existem casos onde você não possui o sistema e passa ser uma aplicação totalmente em front-end, mas mesmo assim seria difícil e custoso, descobrir todos os casos de teste possíveis. Não estou dizendo que não é possível testar interface gráfica, mas que não seria viável, e nem tem garantia de melhor manutenibilidade do sistema, pois os casos de testes seriam superficiais.

Comment: Eu acho que é cabido um ou outro exemplo de caso de teste cabível. Por exemplo, uma função para representar como texto uma coordenada? Coisas que são transformação de dados independente de quesitos como a tela; a representação da coordenada foi apenas um dos primeiros exemplos que me vieram à cabeça. Neste caso, creio que o roteiro de teste (caso de teste? Tem gente que usa os termos com significados distintos) seria o básico dessa talvez edição, com o exemplo em [tag:jasmine] terminando uma resposta de ótimo nível

Comment: Então, isso que escrevi somente o que eu conheço, não conheço jasmine, eu fiz com professor de engenharia de software era muito rígido sobre isso, ele só se baseava em regras de ISOs das vida.

Comment: Para interface existe a disciplina de Interface Homem-Máquina, que mesmo assim, os testes de interface são voltadas para facilitar o uso, e não ver se está funcionando algo. O Famoso, se seu avó consegue usar, então qualquer um pode

Comment: faz sentido ter testes de unidade para verificar casos em que o usuário não preenche, ou preenche incorretamente, campos de um formulário?

Comment: @Leila sim, esse é o caso mais esperado. O Objetivo do teste é trazer rigidez naquilo que o programador esperava.